# Sending a file via HTTP PUT in PHP

Tags: php, curl, stream, http-put

I've been struggling for several hours trying to figure out how to get this work.  I'm trying to send a file via HTTP-PUT to an eXist db.  There is user authentication for the server, so I was trying to do something like this:

I have the URL where the doc is to be PUTted to
I have the username and password for the eXist DB
I have the content that needs to be sent via the PUT

I tried getting to work with cURL but it would fail silently
I tried to use PHP streams, but kept getting "error 201/created" but no file was actually created.

Any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Here's some sample code I tried using PHP streams

```
        $data = file_get_contents($tmpFile);                                                                                                    
         $header = array(
             "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($this->ci->config->item('ws_login') . ':' . $this->ci->config->item('ws_passwd')),
             "Content-Type: text/xml"
         );  
         $params = array(
             'http' => array(
                 'method' => 'PUT',
                 'header' => $header,
                 'content' => $data));
         $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

         $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
```

Comment: Can you provide some source code please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aha!  After a little "rubber ducking" with the grumpy dwarf stuffed doll on my desk here, I figured out the solution:

```
        $data = file_get_contents($tmpFile);
         $params = array(
             'http' => array(
                 'method' => 'PUT',
                 'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($this->ci->config->item('ws_login') . ':' . $this->ci->config->item('ws_passwd')) . "\r\nContent-type: text/xml\r\n",
                 'content' => file_get_contents($tmpFile)
             )
         );
         $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
         $response = @file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);

         return ($response == '');
```

Comment: Can you explain? Was it the addition of the `content` key, or the return statement?

Comment: It was one thing:  changing the way I was building the header.  I still have to suppress the out of file_get_contents as it returns a warning, but I can live with that for now until I find a better way to trap it.

Answer (score 4):

CURL works for me. Here is snippet from my code,

```
                $handle = curl_init ($server_url);

                if ($handle)
                {
                    // specify custom header
                    $customHeader = array(
                        "Content-type: $file_type"
                    );
                    $curlOptArr = array(
                        CURLOPT_PUT => TRUE,
                        CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
                        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $customHeader,
                        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $file_size,
                        CURLOPT_INFILE => $file,
                        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
                        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $user . ':' . $password,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
                    );
                    curl_setopt_array($handle, $curlOptArr);
                    $ret = curl_exec($handle);
                    $errRet = curl_error($handle);
                    curl_close($handle);
```

EDIT: Just updated my code. I don't use authentication myself so this is not tested.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the HTTP authentication stuff to work with cURL.  Can you update that cURL example to use it?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me...

```
function put($_server,$_file,$_data)
{
  $fp = @fsockopen ($_server, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
  if ($fp)
  {
    $p = "PUT $_file HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $p.= "User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (Windows NT 5.0; U) Opera 7.21  [da]\r\n";
    $p.= "Host: $_server\r\n";
    $p.= "Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1\r\n";
    $p.= "Accept-Language: da;q=1.0,en;q=0.9\r\n";
    $p.= "Accept-Charset: windows-1252, utf-8, utf-16, iso-8859-1;q=0.6, *;q=0.1\r\n";
    $p.= "Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0\r\n";
    $p.= "Referer: http://www.nasa.gov/secret/flightplans.asp\r\n";
    $p.= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $p.= "Content-length: ".strlen($_data)."\r\n";
    $p.= "\r\n";
    $p.= $_data;

    //echo($p);
    fputs ($fp, $p);
  }
  else die("dagnabbit : $errstr");

  while ($l=fgets($fp))
    echo($l);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Many of the header lines are probably not necessary... but it works when I talk to my couchdb so I haven't gotten around to weeding them out.

Answer (score 0):

If your eXist-db has the SOAP interface enabled, there's an open-source library called [PheXist](http://query-exist.sourceforge.net/) that would make interacting with the database easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
function _publish($service, $doc) {
    $params = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'PUT'));
    $context = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = fopen($service, 'rb', false, $context);
    $response = fwrite($fp,file_get_contents($doc));
    if ($response === false) {
        return false;
    }
    // Pull out the status code from the header
    $metaData = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    preg_match_all("/HTTP\/1\.[1|0]\s(\d{3})/", $metaData['wrapper_data'][0], $matches);
    $code = end($matches[1]);
    if ($code == 200) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

from
http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2008/01/11/how-to-http-put-a-file-somewhere-using-php/

Comment: That's from my own blog, and I found that it wasn't working correctly. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's hilarious, or sad, or both :O