# php file upload with "file_get_contents" to a server

Tags: php, http, post

is it possible to send a file to a server at the same way like this:

```
$file = 'myfile.txt';

or

$file = file_get_contents(./myfile.txt);

...

$postdata = http_build_query( array( 
'var1' => 'some content',
'var2' => $file 
) );

$opts = array('http' => array( 'method' => 'POST', 'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $postdata ) );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Facebook?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Now is that a rhetoric question, or did you run into problems with file_get_contents and the POST context? Then check out one of the other examples about it in the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#102575

Comment: Did you search for this? [Sending a file via HTTP PUT in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691530/sending-a-file-via-http-put-in-php)

Comment: Your code runs fine with opening the file and including its content in the POST body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use cURL instead of streams? It's so easy:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.url.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'file_input' => '@/path/to/file',
));

curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but its a tedious process. If you want to post something use cURL or with the normal `$_FILE` method.